# Passing a string[] as an object reference to a COM object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, com

I have a webservice that wraps a COM object's functions for the purpose of reducing RPC communication errors. The parameter that I pass to a particular web service is a `string[]`. A problem seems to lie in the COM object function, which requires an object reference.

Some errors will show on the webpage because they come from the COMClass (error 87), others are compiler errors. I've tried to indicate which is which below.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public int WSFunc(string[] StringArray){
    //object StringArr = (object)((object[])StringArr); //returns error 87 in webpage log
    //object StringArr = (object)StringArr; //returns error 87 in webpage log

    //public override int COMClass.Func(ref object pStringList)
    return COMClass.Func(ref StringArr);

    //return COMClass.Func(ref StringArray); //Doesn't build, cannot convert from 'ref string[]' to 'ref object' (CS1503)

    //return COMClass.Func(ref (object)StringArr);  //Doesn't build, A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable (CS1510)
}
```

Also, this produces the same result (error 87 - parameter incorrect):

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string WSFunc(string[] StringArray){
    object[] StringObj = new object[StringArray.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < StringArray.Length; i++){
        StringObj[i] = StringArray[i];
    }

    object MyString = (object)StringObj;
    return ComClass.Func(ref MyString);
}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: You can't pass objects to COM, it has no idea what an object is.  You will have to marshal it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719715(v=vs.71).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719861(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this article should help you setup your marshalling for the com interop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I found [this pdf](http://justlikeamagic.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/marshaling-with-c-pocket-reference.pdf) which explains marshaling in a very simple way. I'm going to create a class which wraps the COM object DLL. I believe the C# code will be able to execute that class, which then marshals the variables... I never expected it to be this difficult to execute a COM object in C#.

Comment: It does require a fair amount of plumbing, but the nice thing is that once you get that up and going it should be pretty easy to keep adding more if you need to.